# Any idea to what $\bar{X}$ refers to in association rules? Is it "not-$X$"?

Tags: association-rules

Any idea to what $\bar{X}$ refers to in association rules? Is it "not-$X$"?

It's in the context of interestingness measure for rule $X \rightarrow Y$.

Comment: I would certainly read it that way. It's standard notation for a set's complement.

Comment: @SeanOwen Yeah although I thought that it could have maybe also meant the average since $\bar{ \cdot}$ means sample mean in stats. And then $X$ is a random variable.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a link to the actual source you are referring to? I haven't myself seen it before in the context of association rules and interestingness.

---

As was pointed out by *@Sean Owen* in his comment, it is one of a few standard notations for saying something is not in a **set** - i.e. the complement. This would make most sense, as we are generally referring to **itemsets** when computing the associations.

Regarding the complement and set notation, [the Wikipedia article contains this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)):

> The absolute complement of A is usually denoted by $${\displaystyle  A^{\complement }}$$
>
> Other notations include $$ {\displaystyle A^{\text{c}}}, \hspace{3mm} \overline A, \hspace{3mm} A',\hspace{3mm} \complement _{U}A \hspace{3mm} and \hspace{3mm} \complement A$$

Of course a *bar* can also mean things such as the mean or expectation value of some values (I have even seen people using it to mean the unobserved or predicted value!), but with the information you provide, the complement seems most likely.

Here also from the same Wiki page linked above for those who are unsure, a visual definition of the complement:

[image]